# Can you use circleci when you have two applications (as directories) within the same repository, do I need to make changes to my config.yml?

Tags: circleci, circleci-orb

In relation to the question above, this issue is that when you use GitHub as the source to build a pipeline for an app it asks for the location of.circleci/config.yml . The thing is though I have a backend and frontend application. When I used circleci briefly in the past  I used circleci with one application inside one repository (a simple use-case). But if I have 2 applications in one github repository can I run the backend and frontend app as separate builds (my preference) by making changes to just one config.yml file or should I just pull the frontend components and backend components out of the my one big repository (which has some other terraform code) and make them into two separate repositories each with a config.yml, which I guess would solve the problem? I just need some input in case anyone has experienced this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is: **you can**! By leveraging [CircleCI's Dynamic Config functionality](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config/). You'll need to make some modifications to your current `config.yml`, though.

[Here's an example](https://circleci.com/docs/using-dynamic-configuration/#execute-specific-workflows-or-steps-based-on-which-files-are-modified) you might find useful; it explains how to execute specific workflows or steps based on which files are modified.